# Running an NUnit test using Mono

Tags: c#, mono, nunit, monodevelop

I am trying to run an nunit test using mono in monodevelop (actually Xamarin Studio).

Here is my test:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace Test
{
    [TestFixture ()]
    public class Test
    {
        [Test ()]
        public void TestCase ()
        {
            Socket socket = new Socket (AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            socket.Connect ("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", xxxx);

            socket.Close ();
        }
    }
}
```

The test runs fine if I use the Microsoft .NET Runtime, but when I switch to Mono 3.3.0 (master/6cd4ddc) the following occurs:

- When running the test without the debugger, nothing happens. The bullets remain gray. The stats indicate that no tests were successfull, inconclusive, failed or ignored.
- When running the test with the debugger, a "Disassembly +" tab opens up and the following line is highlighted:

  00000048   ldstr "Exception in TestRunnerThread"

which doesn't really mean anything to me. Allowing the test to continue gives me a NullReferenceException.

What am I missing?

Comment: At the point where the exception occurs, what does the call stack tell you?